# Is there a name for this type of wavevector?

Tags: waves, terminology, conventions, fourier-transform, wavelength

When we say wavevector we often mean a vector $\mathbf k$ that is related to the direction and wavelength of a plane wave, given by $e^{i\,\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf x}$. I have to write something about Fourier transforms and I define the following vector:
$$\boldsymbol \lambda=\frac{2\pi}{k^2}\mathbf k=\frac{2\pi}{k}\hat{\mathbf k}$$
In other words a vector which is in the same direction as $\mathbf k$ and whose magnitude is the wavelength. When you draw the wavefronts of the plane wave it points from one wavefront to the next as shown here (please ignore $\mathbf a_1,\mathbf a_2$)

[image]

Is this is a known quantity and does it have a name?

Answer (score 0):

$\vec\lambda$ is a vector that describes the wavelength.
It's the displacement from one wavefront to the next along the perpendicular to the wavefront. It essentially describes the direction of a "ray".

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. I might not have been clear but I'm mostly interested in the name of this object to describe it in writing. I could give it a name myself but if there's already a known name then I would just introduce confusion.